# Postgres/VirtualEnv/Flask

Tags: postgresql, virtualenv, flask-sqlalchemy

This one may be for the experts!

**So here is the problem:**

I have a flask app that gets its data from Postgresql and it runs fine in my normal environment. I tried to deploy it locally using `virtualenv` and after `pip install`ing all the requirements the only one that gave me trouble is `psycopg2` which appears to be dependency of Postgresql.

I then used [this amazing article](http://www.marinamele.com/2013/12/how-to-set-django-app-on-heroku-part-i.html/) to help me install it, by putting 
`export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin:$PATH` to the .bash_profile file.

But now I get this error: 
`Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib` ...`Image not found`

What is going on?

Comment: Have you tried to install psycopg2 in virtualenv? In my practice I've never had to set PATH in order to make run postgresql under vitualenv.

Comment: I did but I kept getting an error when I tried to install it. The error stopped when I used that article. I just don't understand why it works when I'm out of the virtual environment and not when I'm in it.